# Ошибки nouveau при загрузке и манипуляциях с настройками

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia

Конфигурация

```
# uname -a
Linux embedded 4.1.7-200.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 20:19:24 UTC 2015 x86_64 
# lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1)
# xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x8f cap: 0x7, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:nouveau 
Provider 1: id: 0x47 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 4 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
```

Вывод dmesg

```
[   25.228845] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO write of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x418880 [ IBUS ]
[   25.228863] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC0: 0x419f74 0x00000555 (0x3800820c)
[   25.228922] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO write of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x40880c [ IBUS ]
[   25.228946] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO write of 0x00000002 FAULT at 0x4188ac [ IBUS ]
[   25.228963] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO write of 0xbadf1008 FAULT at 0x419cc0 [ IBUS ]
[   25.228979] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC0: 0x419cc0 0xbadf1008 (0x3800820c)
[   25.229091] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO write of 0xbadf1000 FAULT at 0x419eb4 [ IBUS ]
[   25.229107] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC0: 0x419eb4 0xbadf1000 (0x3800820c)
[   25.229137] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO write of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x40581c [ IBUS ]
[   25.229645] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x404170 0x00000012 (0x0e008201)
[   27.229596] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] HUB_INIT timed out
[   27.229603] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 409000 - done 0x00000204
[   27.229612] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 409000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
[   27.229621] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 409000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000002 0x00000009
[   27.229624] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 502000 - done 0x00000300
[   27.229630] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 502000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
[   27.229636] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] 502000 - stat 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
[   27.229637] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] init failed, -16
```

Монитор подключался на разные видеокарты, изображение в наличии, ошибка остаётся.
Гугление говорит что ошибке несколько лет, как исправить не понятно.

**Вопрос:** В чём заключается ошибка и как её исправить? 
Мне достаточно ссылки на работающий "рецепт".

PS: Ошибки в логах, сами по себе не беспокоят, при попытке  подключить два монитора, падает графическая оболочка XFCE, последующий вход невозможен без отключения второго монитора. А в логах появляются те же ошибки.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.